# Oracle Sql Duplicate rows when joining new table

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I am using oracle sql to join tables. I use the following code:

```
SELECT 
T.TRANSACTION_KEY,
PR.ACCOUNT_KEY,
T.ACCT_CURR_AMOUNT,
T.EXECUTION_LOCAL_DATE_TIME,
TC.DESCRIPTION,
T.OPP_ACCOUNT_NAME,
T.OPP_COUNTRY,
PT.PARTY_TYPE_DESC,
P.PARTY_NAME,
P.CUSTOM_SMALL_STRING_02,
CO.COUNTRY_NAME,
LE.LIST_CD

FROM TRANSACTIONS T
LEFT JOIN TRANSACTION_CODE TC
 ON T.TRANSACTION_CODE = TC.ENTITY
LEFT JOIN PARTY_ACCOUNT_RELATION PR
 ON T.ACCOUNT = PR.ACCOUNT
LEFT  JOIN PARTY P
 ON PR.PARTY_KEY = P.PARTY_KEY
LEFT  JOIN PARTY_TYPE PT
 ON P.PARTY_TYPE = PT.ENTITY
LEFT  JOIN COUNTRY CO
 ON T.OPP_COUNTRY = CO.ENTITY
LEFT  JOIN LISTED_ENTITY LE
 ON CO.COUNTRY = LE.ENTITY_KEY

WHERE
  PR.PARTY_KEY = '111111111' and T.EXECUTION_LOCAL_DATE_TIME>'2017-01-01';
```

It works fine until now but I want to join another table which has a column in common(ENTITY_KEY) with  PARTY_ACCOUNT_RELATION  table (ACCOUNT_KEY) and I want to include some of the new table's columns but when I do that, it becomes dublicated. I am adding the following lines before "where" statment:

```
LEFT JOIN EVALUATE_RULE ER
 ON PR.ACCOUNT_KEY = ER.ENTITY_KEY
```

Does anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: mysql or Oracle? Please remove incompatible tags

Comment: I am using Oracle sql.

Comment: Move the WHERE clause's PR condition to ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: But even if there is no WHERE it has the same error.

Comment: Please share some sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If joining another table into an existing query causes the existing rows to be duplicated, it is because the table being joined in has duplicate values in the columns that are being used as keys for the join

In your case, if you do

```
SELECT ENTITY_KEY FROM EVALUATE_RULE GROUP BY ENTITY_KEY HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

You'll see which entity_keys are duplicated. When these duplicates are joined to the existing data, the existing data has to be doubled up to permit both rows from EVALUATE_RULE with the same ENTITY_KEY to exist in the result set

You must either de-dupe the table, or put other clauses into your ON condition to further restrict the rows coming from EVALUATE_RULE.

For example, after adding `EVALUATE_RULE` and putting `ER.*` in your `SELECT` list, imagine that you can see that the rows from ER are `status = 'old'` and `status = 'current'` but you know you only want the `current` ones.. So put `AND er.status = 'current'` in your `ON` clause

Your comment indicates that multiple records differ by some column you don't care about, so this technique will just select only one row:

```
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT e.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e.entity_key ORDER BY e.name) as rown FROM evaluate_rule e) er
ON
  er.entity_key = pr.account_key and 
  er.rown = 1
```

If you want info on why this works, run that sql in isolation:

```
SELECT e.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e.entity_key ORDER BY e.name) as rown FROM evaluate_rule e

ORDER BY e.entity_key -- i added this to make it more clear what is going on. You don't need it in your main query
```

It just assigns a number to each row in the table, the number restarts at 1 every time entity_key changes, so we can then select all those with `rown = 1`

If it turns out you DO want something specific like "the latest row from evaluate_rule", you can use something like this:

```
SELECT e.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e.entity_key ORDER BY e.created_date DESC) as rown FROM evaluate_rule e
```

Now the latest `created_date` row will always have `rown = 1`

Comment: What is different in the records is their NAME field, which does't make a difference for me. Is there a way to select just one of the double records?

Comment: @zahrarabiei Added some advice

Answer (score 1):

So far as I can understain from your description, table EVALUATE_RULE has moro records with ACCOUNT_KEY=ENTITY_KEY.

You can change your query section:

```
LEFT JOIN EVALUATE_RULE ER  ON PR.ACCOUNT_KEY = ER.ENTITY_KEY
```

to

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ENTITY_KEY FROM EVALUATE_RULE) ER  ON PR.ACCOUNT_KEY = ER.ENTITY_KEY
```

If you post structure of EVALUATE_RULE (indicating PK columns) I can change my answer to let you includ EVALUATE_RULE columns in final query.

Comment: While that may work, it's nearly useless because it doesn't add anything to the query! All it does is join in a distinct set of the values you already know. Remember that the OP wants to "include some of the new table's columns". Using DISTINCT to squash duplicates is a tenet of lame/lazy SQL practice in most situations. It would be better to identify which of the new rows from EVALUATE_RULE are undesirable and exclude them to get unique ENTITY_KEYS. not just to dedupe afte rthe fact

Comment: @CAius, I see, as specified now in answer I wait info about table structure.